# Remove Duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like below:

```
SuppID   AreaID     SuppNo   SupName    SupPrice
------------------------------------------------
1        3            526    ANC         100 
1        3            985    JTT         200
3        4            100    HIK         300
```

In the above table, for same SuppID(1) and same AreaID(3), different SuppNo are there (526 & 985) in two different rows.

In this scenario , I'd like to make those two rows into a single row with SuppNo field as blank.

Also my output result should display rows with all the columns.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
 DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (SuppID INT, AreaID INT, SuppNo VARCHAR(5), SupName VARCHAR(5), SupPrice INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 1,3,'526','ANC',100 UNION
SELECT 1,3,'985','JTT',200 UNION
SELECT 3,4,'100','HIK',300 

-- select data before updates
SELECT * FROM @TABLE

-- add a row count by AreaID/SuppID
;WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *
       ,SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY AREAID,SUPPID) AS ROWCNT
FROM @TABLE
)

-- set the SuppNo blank on rows that have more than 1 match
UPDATE T1 SET SuppNo='' WHERE ROWCNT>1

-- add a row # by AreaID/SuppID
;WITH T2 AS 
(
SELECT *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AREAID,SUPPID ORDER BY AREAID,SUPPID) AS ROWID
FROM @TABLE
)

-- delete duplicate rows    
DELETE 
FROM T2
WHERE ROWID>1

-- select data after updates    
SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```